# Fake the Android USB Debug settings

Tags: adb, settings, usb-debugging, magisk, root-cloak

I'm trying to get a certain NFC tap-and-pay app to work. It's called Nexi-Pay and AFAIK is only available in Italy. Due to "security concerns" they deny access to the app to rooted Android users. I managed to get past the root check with Magisk Hide, but now the app says that I have to disable "Android USB Debugging" to use it. Now, I tried doing so and it worked, but since it is a feature I use very often, it would be a pain to switch it on and off every time I need to pay for something.

How can I make the app think ADB is disabled while it's actually not, a-la-MagiskHide?

Comment: Another approach would be using an automation app like [tag:tasker] or MacroDroid which, whenever your Nexi app is started (comes to foreground) could disable USB Debugging. This is just a raw idea; I haven't checked which automation apps can toggle that setting.

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks! Apparently it needs Xposed, which I don't have. I'll install it and check if it works when I have some time

Comment: @izzy: Macrodroid can't do this directly. Maybe possible with a shell command run by it though

Comment: @beeshyams AFAIR there's a corresponding `setprop` command, but that might need "elevated privileges". Not sure which one is responsible: `[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]`, `[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]`, `[persist.service.adb.enable]: [1]`, `[init.svc.adbd]: [running]` (this one might need an `svc` command to be toggled) … I'd first check with `getprop` what they are set to, and then start with the second one (removing `adb` from it). Can be tried with `adb shell getprop …` for convenience ;)

Comment: @Izzy : Thanks. I'd seen [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175991/131553) too earlier but it went over my head. I think I will pass this as it requires an understanding which I dint have. This for the pointer though , it may help others :)

Comment: Ah, yes @beeshyams – that's the ones in the new syntax (starting with ~MM, `setprop` got replaced by `settings` on most devices/ROMs). Good find!

Comment: [Hide USB debugging mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redlee90.hideusbdebugging) didn't work with your app. Just checked. Deleting answer

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Magisk and then install the "MagiskHide Props Config" module. After this applications won't be able to detect if ADB is enabled.

Magisk can also hide the root availability. Just enable the hide feature and add the application to the list.

An app I tested reported 5 "security" issues. Enabling Magisk hide (and adding the app to the list) removed 3 of them, and adding the "MagiskHide Props Config" module removed the other 2. One of the remaining 2 is known to be the "Android USB Debugging".

You don't need to do any extra stuff. The module is designed to fool transaction software. In my case the app uses the veritran API, very common on bank apps.