# NexiPay app and Magisk

Tags: magisk

I'm trying to run a banking app called **NexiPay** (I guess it's available only in italy), but it doesn't start because it recognizes my system as rooted. I'm running LineageOS 15 (Android 8.1) and GApps.

So I've installed Magisk. Current version (24.3) seems to be different from what Magisk used to be some months ago. For example, there's no Magisk Hide and Magisk website has not been updated yet.

How can I hide the root to this app?
When I launch NexiPay, Magisk tells me that it's asking for root access.

Answer (score 1):

After following the other solution, it still wouldn't work for me.

I managed to make it work by going into the Magisk settings and selecting the option to hide the Magisk app.

Answer (score 0):

Magisk 24.3 uses a new feature called **DenyList** instead of Magisk Hide.
From one of John Wu's (the creator of magisk) [tweets](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1445598601372069890?lang=en),

> - The new "DenyList" feature of upcoming Magisk versions is me preserving portions of the of hiding codebase and transform it into something I felt is valuable
> - DenyList, however, is only meant to "revert all Magisk changes". It will not attempt to manipulate any other signals on the device

Along with Denylist, in Magisk 24.3 there is also something called **Zygisk**. Basically, Zygisk will [run parts of Magisk in the zygote process](https://9to5google.com/2021/08/29/magisk-android-changes-google/).
(Note: if you want to enable DenyList, you will need to enable Zygisk first.)

To hide root from Nexi pay, just enable DenyList to target NexiPay app. You can find it in the settings from Magisk Manager app.

1. Tap settings icon at top right corner of screen
2. Enable zygisk (this will require a reboot)
3. After the reboot, go back to the settings menu and check that "Enforce DenyList is selected"
4. Choose "Configure DenyList" and select NexiPay app

Comment: Actually I did already try this and it didn't work. I've just tried it again and it's not enough. I guess NexiPay is checking other stuff. I've read I should disable USB Debugging and remove the TWRP directory in the main root; I did both but didn't help. @Manchineel perhaps you can help? You're the only one who [wrote about NexiPay in this forum](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/192019/fake-the-android-usb-debug-settings).

Comment: @fedelibre was NexiPay already recognising your device as rooted before you installed magisk? If so DenyList probably won't help to hide, you might want to explore [in this direction](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1457932567928193025).

Comment: Yes, NexiPay recognized my device as rooted before I installed magisk. Then I uninstalled NexiPay, installed magisk, reinstalled NexiPay. But it doesn't help. So I should look for alternatives to Magisk... I will investigate and report here any success or failure with other modules.

Comment: I'm also interested in the solution to this problem. I have a suspicion that the app is somehow detecting that the bootloader has been unblocked, or that a custom ROM has been installed, independently from the actual rooted status. But I have no actual competence to try and solve this.