# Any way to force "USB debugging enabled" status using adb commands, with broken phone screen

Tags: adb, usb, recovery-mode, broken-screen

I am trying to access my phone, after screen is broken (no way to enter swipe access or pin). I have installed Android Studio and am able to navigate to the folder containing adb in a command prompt, and enter the "adb devices" command where it shows an alpha-numeric return (I am assuming representing my phone) with an "unauthorized" status (which I am assuming means that USB debugging is disabled).

I get this returned when I try to access it via the "adb shell input text xxxx" command:

error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

Is there any way to force a enabled status? I have no way of navigating any settings or apps as the screen is inaccessible.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! A good starting point would be our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which holds some first aid and links on this topic. Also check the questions using it. As for the other tags you've chosen: Are you trying to access the device while booted into recovery mode? If not, that tag doesn't fit :)

Comment: Is your device rooted?
This [thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120394/can-i-enable-usb-debugging-using-adb) will help you.

Comment: You can connect a mouse using OTG cable to the device.