# Access "locked" phone storage

Tags: adb, internal-storage

I was given an **Archos Diamond S** phone to repair. The phone can't boot after an OTA update, it's stuck on the booting screen (no boot loop).

When it's stuck on the boot logo I can access the files however this is really slow and make explorer.exe crash everytime I want to perform an ation. Furthermore I want to access the root of sdcard **so I can backup some apps data**.

The only think I can do is boot in factory or in recovery mode. However in recovery mode I can only use adb in sideload mode and can't pull anything. I could try to force the OTA update via adb but I **can't find the firmware for this model**.

I then wanted to install a custom recovery that would enable android debug mode (like TWRP) and pull files with adb but I didn't find any for this model.

***Do you know any way I could access the phone storage and create a backup of thoses files before wipe data/factory reset ?***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use ADB.

1. Connect your device to PC/Mac in Recovery mode.
2. Test connection. Type `./adb devices` (MAC) OR `adb devices` (WINDOWS).
3. Assuming you want to download DCIM folder, type `./adb pull sdcard/DCIM <optional_dir>`

Use `./adb` on Mac and `adb` on Windows.

You can also download the complete `/sdcard` folder as a full backup.

Comment: USB Debug was not activated on the phone. Thus I can't do that, my computer won't detect the phone using adb. That's why I wanted to install TWRP so I can use adb.

Comment: read this to enable USB debugging using ADB: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120394/can-i-enable-usb-debugging-using-adb/120441#120441

Comment: The device is not rooted and is not detected by adb except when in sideload mode.

Comment: I checked my guide on my Nexus 5 which is not rooted and USB debugging was OFF. I was able to 'pull' files.

Comment: I will give it a try tonight. However I know the device doesn't appear as "connected" while in recovery mode when I `adb devices`

Comment: When in Factory mode the device appears in device manager and is unanthorized in adb. In recovery mode it doesn't appear in device manager, neither with adb.

Comment: Is bootloader unlocked?

Comment: I don't think so. Neither my friend or me unlocked it